# Linear index of the maximum of a multi-dimensional matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Let's say I have a `3-dimensional` matrix and have computed the `max` along the second dimension, and want to get the linear indices of the max values. However, the `max-function` only returns the subscripts along one dimension.

```
A = randn([5,5,5]);        % Generate random matrix
[M, Ind] = max(A,[],2);    % Take the max along dimension 2
```

How do I transfer the `index` to `linear indexing`, such that

```
M == A(Ind)
```

becomes true?

My intention for this problem is that I have `two` `multi-dimensional` matrices and need to compute the `max` in the `first` one. Then, I want to access the values in the `second` matrix at exactly those positions where I found a max in the `first` one.

Comment: If you care about performance, here's a quick test for the solutions posted here - https://ideone.com/cOV5D3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `sub2ind`:

```
A = randn([5,5,5]);       
[M, col] = max(A,[],2);   

[m,n,o] = size(A);

dim1 = mod((0:m*o-1)', m)+1;
dim2 = col(:);
dim3 = ceil((1:m*o)/m)';

ind = sub2ind(size(A), dim1, dim2, dim3)
```

verify it works with

```
isequal(M(:), A(ind))
```

to get them to have the same shape as `M`:

```
reshape(ind, m, 1, o)
```

Comment: Great comment, with your help I become able to manage the problem. I had trouble understanding to parameters sub2ind needs. However, I could extend this solution to even five dimensions in matrix A.

Answer (score 1):

Create the indices for the other dimensions.

In dim 1 the index needs to change fastest: `[1,2,...,size(A,1)]` and this `size(A,3)` times:

```
idx1 = repmat((1:size(A,1))',size(A,3),1);
```

In dim 2 the index is given by `Ind`.

In dim 3 the index need to change slowest: `[1,1,...,1]` for `size(A,1)` times and then `[2,2,...,2]` and so on until `size(A,3)`.

```
idx3 = ones(size(A,1),1)*(1:size(A,3));
```

Access single values:

```
 M_ = A(sub2ind(size(A),idx1(:),Ind(:),idx3(:)));
```

Compare:

```
M(:) == M_
```

Comment: This solution is quite similar to that of Dan, thanks for the explanation of the parameter shape (idx1, idx3, ...)

Answer (score 1):

**3-dimensional case**:

```
[m, n, p] = size(A);
[M, Ind] = max(A,[],2);
LinInd = bsxfun(@plus, (1:m).', (0:p-1)*m*n); %'//
LinInd = LinInd(:) + (Ind(:)-1)*m;
```

The desired linear index is `LinInd`. This produces

```
A(LinInd) == M(:)
```

with all `true` entries (note you need `(:)` on the right-hand side so that the comparison makes sense).

**General multi-dimensonal case**:

```
d = 3; %// dimension along which max will be computed
s = size(A);
sLow = prod(s(1:d-1));
sHigh = prod(s(d+1:end));
[M, Ind] = max(A,[],d);
LinInd = bsxfun(@plus, (1:sLow).', (0:sHigh-1)*sLow*s(d)); %'//
LinInd = LinInd(:) + (Ind(:)-1)*sLow;
```

Comment: Quite short solution. However might be tricky to extend to multiple dimensions. I have not stated this in the problem set, but however, try to manage problems in the general way. Thanks.

Comment: The multi-dimensional case worked great for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @gtownescapee Great!

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose `A` and `B` are the two matrices you have and you need to get `max` indices from `A` and use those indices to index into `B` for the desired output. One approach to achieve the same could be like this -

```
%// Your code to get Ind
A = randn([5,5,5]);        % Generate random matrix
[M, Ind] = max(A,[],2);    % Take the max along dimension 2

%// ------- Solution code -------------

%// Get the size of A
[n1,n2,n3] = size(A)

%// Linear indices corresponding to column and third dimension indices
col_dim3_lin_idx = bsxfun(@plus,(Ind-1)*n1,permute([0:n3-1]*n1*n2,[1 3 2]))

%// Finally get the overall linear indices
linear_index = bsxfun(@plus,col_dim3_lin_idx,[1:n1]') %//'

%// Get the corresponding elements from B
out = B(linear_index)
```

---

Slightly different way to have the desired linear indices as a 2D array would be like this -

```
[n1,n2,n3] = size(A) %// Get the size of A
idx = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,squeeze((Ind-1)*n1),[0:n3-1]*n1*n2),[1:n1]')
```

`idx(:)` would be the column vector of linear indices with this new approach, which you can index into `B` i.e. `B(idx(:))` to have the desired output as a column vector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I guess the solution with sub2ind might be faster since your codes require bsxfun operations and permutations, which may slow down the code. However, I have not evaluated it.

Comment: @dast I think you should try out all these solutions and see for yourself for the runtime comparisons. Also, let me ask you - What must be the output format for the linear indices? Are you looking to have a column vector of indices or keep it of the same dimensions as Ind, which is a `N x 1 x M` array.

Comment: Yes, the linear indices should be a column vector. A N x 1 x M array is that what the max function returns.

Comment: @dast Since you were asking about runtime performance, you can check out those here - https://ideone.com/cOV5D3